# Tamaño ancho automático

Tags: css, bootstrap

Supongamos que tengo lo siguiente:

```
<div class="modal-body" style="">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4" style="display: flex;justify-content: between">
        <input style="display: inline" type="number" ng-model="slider" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope ng-not-empty">
        <input style="display: inline" type="number" ng-model="slider" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope ng-not-empty">
        <input style="display: inline" type="number" ng-model="slider" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope ng-not-empty">
        <input style="display: inline" type="number" ng-model="slider" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope ng-not-empty">
        <input style="display: inline" type="number" ng-model="slider" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope ng-not-empty">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Me gustaría que el ancho de cada input sea automático, ya que los years peudes ser un array de N elementos

NOTA: 
- uso Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.6
- los inputs se tienes que ajustar al col-4 en una sola fila

Comment: Creo que tienes que añadir la clase form-control a tu input. Así tendría el 100% siempre.

Comment: poniendo lo que me comentas se divide en 5 filas, es decir, mete un salto de linea

Comment: prueba al div padre ponerle `display: flex` y que los input hijos tengan `display: inline`. También en el padre `justify-content: between`

Comment: @David actualizo mi post como me comentas, ahora me salen dos inputs en cada fila

Comment: tiene que ser el padre inmediato, no el padre del padre

Comment: Deberías explicar con más detalle lo que quieres o poner una imagen o esquema del resultado que esperas, cuando dices que el ancho sea automático ¿qué quieres decir?¿se debe ajustar al contenido de los imputs o al ancho de la página? ¿van todos en una fila o pueden pasar a la siguiente si no hay espacio? Falta información para saber que hacer exactamente

Comment: pregunta editada

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con display flex

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4" style="display: flex;justify-content: between">
        <input style="display: inline" type="number" ng-repeat="year in years track by $index" />
    </div>
</div>
```

También usando bootstrap puedes reemplazar los styles por clases predefinidas que hacen lo mismo que el código anterior. Sería de la siguiente manera:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 d-flex justify-content-between">
        <input class="d-inline" type="number" ng-repeat="year in years track by $index" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: lo he probado asi, pero se me descuadra todo

Comment: puedes poner el codigo html que se genera despues del ng-repeat? el código final?

Comment: he modificado mi comentario con lo que me pides

Comment: he probado el html que has puesto y se me ve bien, todos los input en fila (pegados uno al otro) si quisieras separarlos simplemente tendrias que jugar con los margenes y padding. Puedes añadir tambien un pantallazo de como te queda el resultado en la web?

Comment: me salen todo ahora en una misma fila pero el ancho de los inputs no se ajustan

Comment: vale voy a añadir otra respuesta

Answer (score 0):

usando JQuery puedes ajustar el input al tamaño del texto que tienen en su interior de la siguiente manera:

```js
$('input').each(function() {
  $(this).attr('size', $(this).val().length);
});

function resizeInput() {
    $(this).attr('size', $(this).val().length);
}

$('input[type="text"]').keyup(resizeInput).each(resizeInput);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-body" style="">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
        <input type="text" ng-model="slider" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope ng-not-empty" value="10">
        <input type="text" ng-model="slider" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope ng-not-empty" value="555">
        <input type="text" ng-model="slider" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope ng-not-empty" value="8888888">
        <input type="text" ng-model="slider" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope ng-not-empty" value="1">
        <input type="text" ng-model="slider" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope ng-not-empty" value="999999999999">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Para que puedas cambiar el `size` del input, este no puede ser type number, puedes utilizar un type text y hacerlo readonly por ejemplo para que no lo puedan editar, o solo permitir que el usuario introduzca números tambien por javascript. los values son simbólicos para que se vea en el ejemplo.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta @David, el problema es que el cliente necesita que sea number no tipo text, no importa si escribe muchos numero y solo se vea los 3 primeros, mientras los inputs aparezcan del mismo tamaño en el div col-4